# How to fix Physical Memory dump error during installation of windows xp ? Why PC not started?

Tags: windows, windows-xp, installation, troubleshooting, memory-error

My lenovo laptop of i 3 processor , 500 GB Hard disk and 3GB ram.
 It was restated contentiously and shows error physical memory dump complete.

So that I format c drive and trying to install fresh copy of windows XP.
but when installation complete upto 15% it again shows same error that physical memory dump complete with blue screen

What will i do??
 How to fix this bug?

please help me.

Comment: Sidenote : Windows XP isn't supported anymore, I suggest you buy a Windows 7 licence and install that OS instead.

Comment: but my mechanical softwares support only windows xp.

Comment: Fair enough... this looks like a hardware issue, probably faulty RAM. Can you burn this [Memtest](http://www.memtest.org/download/5.01/memtest86+-5.01.iso.zip) ISO to a CD and let it run for a few hours ? It shouldn't display any errors when running, otherwise your RAM is definitely bad.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that the error is related to the fact that XP wasn't meant for this new hardware.

I'd strongly recommend migrating.
I've done so myself with several programs in my organization - It takes some time, but I think it pays off.
Also, if I'm right about XP not able to install on your machine because it's too new, than you'll have to migrate.

Another option, which might be easier, is trying virtual machines, but it depends on how your computer communicates with the mechanical equipment.